# Handling text/plain request in Laravel (sent via navigator.sendBeacon)

Tags: laravel, http, post, laravel-8, navigator

### Problem:

I am trying to get the **content / body** from a **text/plain POST request** in a **Controller** in **Laravel 8**.

Nothing in the docs or numerous google searches worked.

### I have tried:

```
$request->input();
$request->all();
$request->json();
json_encode($request);
```

All of these seem to show that the request is completely empty.

#### Context

This may not be relevant to the solution, but might help other's who are trying to google this problem: The request I am trying to handle with my controller is being sent by navigator.sendBeacon on the client side. The request body is actually stringified JSON, but sendBeacon does not allow you to send requests with content-type JSON. Devtools show the content-type header for this request as 'text/plain'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### My Answer:

**Use `$request->getContent()` to get the content of a text/plain HTTP request.**

And then, if you are in a situation like mine where the text is actually JSON, use `json_decode($request->getContent(),true)` to get a standard PHP array from the content which you can use in your Controller.

*It turned out to be quite simple, but the information was not in the docs, or in any online searches so I thought it would be worthwhile to post to SO anyways...*

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. One note: given that we're getting the data from user-controlled land (the browser) and through a fairly low-level method (`getContent()` comes from the underlying Symfony library), I'd be extra careful with sanitizing it, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data as JSON like this instead

```js
data = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {type : 'application/json'})

navigator.sendBeacon('/your/route/here', data)
```

Comment: how to fit the csrf token into the data blob @jjjrmy?

Comment: You can probably pull it from the session or header and include it in that blob. I haven't tried it though.